# How to measure the distance (in generalized sense) between geographical regions?

Tags: dataset, distance, geospatial

I need to construct a **distance matrix** for a few U.S. counties that are adjacent to one or another, and choosing the **definition of distance** is very tricky. The **shortest path** (i.e the minimum number of times one has to cross county borders to walk from A to B) and **the Vincenty distance** between the most populous cities are not working well already. What are other options?

Also, I read somewhere and some time ago that distance between two geographical regions can be measured by the **strength of "interaction"**. Volume of telephone calls, trajectories of trucks, and frequencies of flights were mentioned. Yet I can't any details about such modeling. **Can somebody refer me to a paper or something? Are there open datasets of those souces available?**

Anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of interaction data, you might be thinking of [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6113118) and [this project](http://senseable.mit.edu/csa/index.html)

I love the idea of using flight data. You could start with [this set hosted at Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/flashgordon/usa-airport-dataset).

In terms of estimating distance between states, the simplest thing you could do that might work is to measure the distance between state capitals.